# htaccess removing index.php and search queries from URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that, for a certain php function to work, needs the url to be:

/topic/index.php?height=###

I would like the URL to read

/topic/

What can I put in the .htaccess file to achieve this?  Can I put one htaccess file in the root, or would I need to put one in each /topic/ directory?

Comment: Are you shooting for `/topic/height/###` ? or `/topic/###` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might work for your issue:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1/index.php?height=###
```

Of course, that's assuming a static number. If you need a dynamic number or one provided by the client, you're going to need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(\d+)/?$ $1/index.php?height=$2
```